# Condition for including header/footer in WordPress single post file

Tags: ajax, wordpress, include

I'm building a WordPress based AJAX site, where I use jQuery and the .get() method to display content from single post pages onto the same page. Now I don't want to include the header/footer when retrieving this data but I still need to make it SEO friendly and have all the single pages accessible elsewhere. Is it possible to write a condition in the single.php file that would accomplish this?

Tried using

```
<?php if (!is_home()) { get_header(); } ?>
```

When accessing the page in particular it works; the header is included. But if I load the url through .get() on the home page I get all content and end up with a double header. Somehow WP thinks it's at the home location even though it's running the condition remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your AJAX functions at `init hook`:

```
// add_action('init', array($this, 'process_ajax_callback'));
add_action('init', 'process_ajax_callback');
```

And use `exit` just after output your data (using `echo`):

```
function process_ajax_callback()
{
    $output = ''; // your desired output

    // echo json_encode($output);
    echo $output; 

    exit; // kill script here
}
```